AG Grid - Conflicting module registry statuses when activating side bar
We're using AG Grid Enterprise 30.1.0 in Angular 15, and trying to activate the Side Bar accessory.
When setting sideBar: true, the side bar fails to appear and we get the following console log (plus a similar one for FiltersToolPanelModule):
AG Grid: unable to use Column Tool Panel as the ColumnsToolPanelModule is not registered. Check if you have registered the module:
           
    import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
    import { ColumnsToolPanelModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel';
    
    ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ ColumnsToolPanelModule ]);

For more info see: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/modules/

However, if I call ModuleRegistry.__getRegisteredModules() to see which ones are successfully registered, both of those modules are included.
{
    "version": "30.1.0",
    "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/column-tool-panel",
    "beans": [
        null
    ],
    "agStackComponents": [
        {
            "componentName": "AgPrimaryColsHeader"
        },
        {
            "componentName": "AgPrimaryColsList"
        },
        {
            "componentName": "AgPrimaryCols"
        }
    ],
    "userComponents": [
        {
            "componentName": "agColumnsToolPanel"
        }
    ],
    "dependantModules": [
        {
            "version": "30.1.0",
            "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/core",
            "beans": [
                null
            ],
            "agStackComponents": [
                {
                    "componentName": "AgWatermark"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "version": "30.1.0",
            "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/row-grouping",
            "beans": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
            ],
            "agStackComponents": [
                {
                    "componentName": "AgGridHeaderDropZones"
                }
            ],
            "userComponents": [
                {
                    "componentName": "agGroupColumnFilter"
                },
                {
                    "componentName": "agGroupColumnFloatingFilter"
                }
            ],
            "dependantModules": [
                {
                    "version": "30.1.0",
                    "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/core",
                    "beans": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "agStackComponents": [
                        {
                            "componentName": "AgWatermark"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "version": "30.1.0",
            "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/side-bar",
            "beans": [
                null
            ],
            "agStackComponents": [
                {
                    "componentName": "AgHorizontalResize"
                },
                {
                    "componentName": "AgSideBar"
                },
                {
                    "componentName": "AgSideBarButtons"
                }
            ],
            "dependantModules": [
                {
                    "version": "30.1.0",
                    "moduleName": "@ag-grid-enterprise/core",
                    "beans": [
                        null
                    ],
                    "agStackComponents": [
                        {
                            "componentName": "AgWatermark"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

In addition to the default sideBar = true, we've tried activating both the column and filter tool panels individually (e.g. sideBar = ['columns']).  We've also tried registering these modules directly with the table, rather than through ModuleRegistry.  Other enterprise modules we've installed are functioning without issue.
What could cause AG Grid to be reporting conflicting information here, and how can we resolve it?
Thanks!

Upgrading ag-grid to 32.1.0 did the work for me. I'm not completely sure what happened and on their changelog I was not able to find anything related.
https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=32.1.0

Thanks!  I figured updating the version was the likely solution, but hadn't actually tried it; this is as high as we can go without a new enterprise license.
If anyone has a viable fix without updating, I'd still love to hear it.
